# Ovrerriding methods and handling exceptions

Tags: java

I am aware of Liskov Substitution Principle.

But I still have a question about the following code:

Below code has parent class A and subclass B. `testException` method is overridden in B subclass such that it does not throw any checked exception.

```
public class A {
    public void testException() throws IOException{
        //some code with IO  
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void testException() {
        //no IO code
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        first:
        try {// compilation error
            B b = new B();
            b.testException();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        second:
        try {
            A a = new B();// Why does not cause compilation error?
            a.testException();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

    }

}
```

In Test class, try-catch block labelled `first` doesn't compile. But second block does without any problems. Why is that?

Update: I think second block is compiling only because of runtime polymorphism, that object a of type `A` can be pointing to any subclass during runtime, and compiler would not have a clue about it, right?

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect and won't compile at all. Please include the **actual** code instead of that atrocity.

Comment: I indented your code but it doesn't show problem you are facing correctly since `testException` is not even a method there. Please correct your example so we could actually use it and reproduce error you are getting.

Comment: updated with method calling in try catch blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. Now, why do you think happens here? Why do you think first code compiles fine, but second doesn't? (try to think about if there is any chance that in second block IOException will be thrown).

Comment: I think its due to runtime polymorphism,as compiler sometimes cannot be sure of the runtime object it will be pointing to, in cases like dependency injection. So first case is starightforward, but second case has RTP which might prevent complier from causing any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think second block is compiling only because of runtime polymorphism, that object a of type A can be pointing to any subclass during runtime, and compiler would not have a clue about it, right?

Yes, that is the case. In `first` block we are sure that `b`

```
B b = ...
b.testException();
```

is of type of `B` which means that it can hold instance of class `B` or its subclass. Since compiler knows that `testException()` method in class `B` (or its subclasses) will never throw any `IOException` (subclasses can't add new checked exceptions to overridden methods) it informs you that you are trying to do something unnecessary (creating dead code - code which will never be executed) which in this case is handling exception which doesn't have chances to be thrown here.

This situation is different in case of `second` block because there we have

```
A a = ....
a.testException();
```

Here compiler can't be sure which object will be held by `a` (at least not in its current version, maybe in the future this behaviour will be improved). So while it is possible that it will hold instance of class `B`, it is also possible that it will be instance of class `A`. So since there is possibility that `testException` will throw `IOException` and compilers doesn't see any reason to stop you from handling it (actually handling it is mandatory here because of that posibility).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is coming from the fact that the testException method in your B class does not throw an IO exception, therefore there is no possible exception to be caught in your try/catch block.

Comment: My question is, why the second block does not throw any compilation error?

Comment: Possibly because you do not actually use the @Override tag, so it is still using the method from class A, however I would need to test that to make sure.

Comment: @user2296988 Why do you think second block shouldn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

```
 A a = new B();
 a.testException();
```

the compiler will ask for a `try-catch` block or a `throws` clause here because polymorphism is  a runtime phenomenon , and compiler is resolving the method call at compile time .

so , it sees that `testException()` in `A` throws `IOException` and thus asks for a `try-catch` block or `throws` clause.